# jenssegers mongodb update nested object

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I have a mongodb table, that contains a fixture of a soccer tournament, so every matchweek looks like this:

```
"number": 1,
"games" : [
        {
                "estadio" : "G C",
                "arbitro" : "M",
                "resultado" : "vs",
                "editor" : "Pepe",
                "id" : 1,
                "equipo_local" : "Las Palmas",
                "equipo_visitante" : "Villareal",
                "fecha" : "10/05/2018",
                "horario" : "16:00",
                "hora" : "12:12"
        },
        {
                "estadio" : "Ciudad de Valencia",
                "arbitro" : "A Confirmar",
                "resultado" : "vs",
                "editor" : "No Asignado",
                "id" : 2,
                "equipo_local" : "Levante",
                "equipo_visitante" : "Deportivo",
                "fecha" : "28/01/2019",
                "horario" : "18:00"
        },
        ..
      ]
"number": 2,
"games": [..]
...
```

I'm working with Laravel and Jessengers, and I want to update an element inside a specific matchweek and a specific game.
For example, I want to change the editor of matchweek 1 and game with id 1, but I'm having trouble doing that

With this, I can get the matchweek but how do I continue?

```
$number = (int) request('number');
$f = Fecha::where('number', $number)->first();
```